# Making upvoters realize there is a better solution

Tags: discussion, upvotes

In some questions the user who answers first is upvoted highly even though there is some logic error or the output is not exact.

After one or two minutes, my answer comes up with an appropriate solution, and the OP accepts my answer. But still the *first answer still has high upvotes*.

**I know I can't tell people to upvote, but should I make them realize this?**

How should I handle this situation?

Generally **I comment** below that this answer has issues or prefer to downvote and the user who answered first just changes the solution. And *it's fine*. But what about high upvotes *for a wrong (or imperfect)* solution?

Comment: Voters are not obligated to explain their votes.

Comment: Agree but I am asking for the imperfect answer who upvoted highly what about that I don't care who upvoted who but I care the solution must be correct what OP was asking for.

Comment: Consider the downvotes to mean roughly (at least this is what I think) - "Of course you're going to think your own answer is better. And even if it is, we don't see this as a problem - everyone is entitled to cast their upvotes when and how they see fit - this is how the system works." (and commenting on an **incorrect** answer, then optionally downvoting if the issue doesn't get fixed, is exactly what you should do - note "incorrect", not "imperfect" - no-one's perfect).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Users are free to use their votes however they like, so long as they are not engaging in voter fraud.  If you're expecting some answer that explains what you should do about votes that you don't like, or about the way users vote, you won't get it from me.  There's nothing you can do about that.

**Further Reading**
[Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: And to make a point I AM UPVOTING THIS ON SIGHT

Comment: @Robert Harvey Okay Thanks It simply means there is nothing I can do in this situation other than downvoting!!!

Comment: I don't see how downvoting will help you here.

Comment: Because user who gave answer first don't have perfect answer but still highvotes!!! I mean imperfect answer can be the reason of downvoting isn't it?

Comment: Sure, if that floats your boat.  Note that the tooltip on the downvote arrow says "this answer is not useful."  That's how you should judge the answer.

Comment: Yes but I can't see other solution I will definetly revert downvote after User EDIT answer and provide correct solution !!!   :)